# Adding destructor logic causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

There are a few questions already with a similar title, but I've been unable to find one that seg-faults when the destructor ***isn't*** called.

I've been writing a templated doubly-linked-list (for fun and practice) and up to now, it has been working correctly (tested with inserts and deletes all over the place, testing edge cases etc).

I hadn't correctly implemented RAII up to this point so it is pretty *unsafe* to actually use right now (copies will be a problem, and unless you clear the list first, it will leak memory like an upturned bucket if it goes out of scope).

I originally had an empty destructor:

```
template<class T>
dll<T>::~dll()
{}
```

a find function:

```
template<class T>
int dll<T>::find_node(T data)
{
  int index = 0;
  dllnode<T>* current_node = end[0];
  while (current_node)
  {
    if (current_node->data == data)
      return index;
    current_node = current_node->link[1];
    index++;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

and a working `del_node` function.

Now, the problem I am having, is that when I try to clear the list of any data in the destructor:

```
template<class T>
dll<T>::~dll()
{
    while ( del_node(0) ){}    //returns 0 if no nodes left to delete.
}
```

my (unchanged) `find_node()` function causes a seg-fault.

As the *only* change to the code is in the destructor, I'm 'assuming' that it is related, but I don't see how.  The destructor should never be called as the dll object is on the stack and is in scope until the end of main.

With the empty destructor, the code runs as intended.

Here is the current example code:

dll_example.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <climits>
#include "dll.h"

void printout(dll<int> list)
{
    std::cout<<"\nnumber of nodes: "<<list.get_node_count()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"list contents:"<<std::endl;
    list.print_list();
}

int main()
{
    dll<int> list;

    std::cout<<"created list" << std::endl;

    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
    {
        int j = list.add_node(i, 5);
        std::cout<<"added a node, value: "<<i<<", index: "<< j << std::endl;
    }

    printout(list);

    std::cout<<"\nfinding '8'" << std::endl;                    //Prints this line
    int index = list.find_node(8);                           
    std::cout<<"deleting '8' (index: "<<index<<")"<< std::endl; //never gets this far
    list.del_node(index);

    printout(list);

    std::cout<<"\ndeleting #1" << std::endl;
    list.del_node(1);

    printout(list);

    std::cout<<"\ndeleting #0" << std::endl;

    do{                                     //manually delete all entries including 
                                            //a del_node() call on empty list (works)
      printout(list);
      std::cout<<"deleting #0" << std::endl;
    }while(list.del_node(0));
    printout(list);
}
```

Faulty Output:

```
$ ./dll_example.exe
created list
added a node, value: 0, index: 0
added a node, value: 1, index: 1
added a node, value: 2, index: 2
added a node, value: 3, index: 3
added a node, value: 4, index: 4
added a node, value: 5, index: 5
added a node, value: 6, index: 5
added a node, value: 7, index: 5
added a node, value: 8, index: 5
added a node, value: 9, index: 5

number of nodes: 10
list contents:
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5,

finding '8'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Empty Destructor Output:

```
...
list contents:
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5,

finding '8'
deleting '8' (index: 6)

number of nodes: 9
list contents:
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 7, 6, 5,
...
```

Comment: _"and a working del_node" function_ What does it actually do?

Comment: You are passing a list to `printout` by value. This uses your copy constructor *and* your destructor. The rule of three does not forgive, the rule of three does not forget (and becomes the rule of five the moment you look the other way.) Respect it.

Comment: @n.m. I can't believe I missed that.  Just changed to `printout(list<int>& list)` and it works - it'll be because of the lack of a copy constructor right now, correct? (facepalm, I did say it was for _practice_ right?).  Post it as an answer and I'll accept. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void printout(dll<int> list)
```

`list` is local to `printout`. The destructor will be called on return.

```
printout(list);
```

This will use the copy constructor to pass the argument.

If your copy constructor does not match the destructor, Bad Things Will Happen.

If you want to play with your class without implementing the copy constructor and the copy assignment operator, it is best to declare them as `private` without implementing them:

```
template<class T>
class dll {
 private:
   dll(dll&);             // no implementation
   void operator=(dll&);  // no implementation
 ...
```

The compiler will yell at you as soon as you accidentally use the copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like `printout()` is the culprit.  You're passing the list directly, which will invoke the copy constructor.  Unless you've defined a copy constructor explicitly, you'll get the default, which does a shallow copy.  I see pointers to `dllnode`s referenced in `find_node()`.  The default shallow copy will just duplicate the top level pointer, meaning that the new `dll<int>` in `printout()` will have the same payload of `dllnode`s as the outer one in `main()`.  Those will get deleted when `printout()` returns, leaving the outer one in `main()` with a dangling pointer, leading to the seg fault.

Quick fix.  Change the declaration of `printlist()` to this:

```
void printout(dll<int> &list)
```

That'll pass the list by reference which will (a) be faster, and (b) won't invoke the copy constructor and cause the destructor to be called.

In any case, you should create a copy costructor, and maybe an `operator=` while you're at it, both of which need to do a deep copy, i.e. duplicate the entire list of `dllnode`s.  There's plenty of placed these might get used, and in this case the default (shallow) methods for these are going to cause all sorts of problems.